# On Raspberry Pi, cross compile helloworld in x86 with native gdb doesn't show source info

Tags: gdb, raspberry-pi

When I cross compile the helloworld code on x86 target raspberry pi, the pi's native gdb doesn't show the symbol info.    Native pi's gcc works fine.

**Cross compiler:**

```
gcc version 4.8.3 20140106 (prerelease) (crosstool-NG linaro-1.13.1-4.8-2014.01 - Linaro GCC 2013.11)
```

**Native Compiler:**

```
gcc version 4.6.3 (Debian 4.6.3-14+rpi1)
```

**ls -al hellow***

```
-rw-rw-r-- 1 pi pi   81 Nov 16 18:54 hellow.c
-rwxrwxr-x 1 pi pi 7080 Nov 16 18:54 hellow_cross_compile
-rwxr-xr-x 1 pi pi 6529 Nov 16 18:57 hellow_native_compile
```

**tlee@raspberrypi ~/mnt/u1404/k_pi/hellow $ gdb hellow_cross_compile**

```
    GNU gdb (GDB) 7.4.1-debian
    Copyright (C) 2012 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
    License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
    This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
    There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.  Type "show copying"
    and "show warranty" for details.
    This GDB was configured as "arm-linux-gnueabihf".
    For bug reporting instructions, please see:
    <http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/bugs/>...
    Reading symbols from /home/tlee/mnt/u1404/k_pi/hellow/hellow_cross_compile...done.
    (gdb) b main
    Breakpoint 1 at 0x8414
    (gdb) r
    Starting program: /home/tlee/mnt/u1404/k_pi/hellow/hellow_cross_compile 

    Breakpoint 1, 0x00008414 in main ()
    (gdb) quit

A debugging session is active.

    Inferior 1 [process 21284] will be killed.

Quit anyway? (y or n) y
```

**tlee@raspberrypi ~/mnt/u1404/k_pi/hellow $ gdb ./hellow_native_compile**

```
GNU gdb (GDB) 7.4.1-debian
Copyright (C) 2012 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.  Type "show copying"
and "show warranty" for details.
This GDB was configured as "arm-linux-gnueabihf".
For bug reporting instructions, please see:
<http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/bugs/>...
Reading symbols from /home/tlee/mnt/u1404/k_pi/hellow/hellow_native_compile...done.
(gdb) b main
Breakpoint 1 at 0x83dc: file hellow.c, line 6.
(gdb) r
Starting program: /home/tlee/mnt/u1404/k_pi/hellow/hellow_native_compile 

Breakpoint 1, main (argc=1, argv=0x7efff7e4) at hellow.c:6
6       printf("hellow\n");
(gdb) quit
A debugging session is active.

    Inferior 1 [process 21307] will be killed.

Quit anyway? (y or n) y
```

**Have anyone encounter this before?  Any idea why and how to fix it?**

Comment: This is missing a lot of important information.  Are the sources in fact available?  What was the working directory, did you use the same compiler arguments, etc?

Comment: @TomTromey   Yes.  Source is available in the same dir.  You can see in in the output of "ls -al hellow*".

Comment: Also gcc and "arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc" both use -g arguments.